# homomorphism and kernels

Tags: group-theory

Find all elements in $\mathbb Z^*_{30}$. Then consider the function $\varphi:\mathbb Z^*_{30}\to \mathbb Z^*_{30}$ given by the formula  $\varphi(x)=x^2$. Prove that $\varphi $ is a homomorphism and compute its kernel.
 this is my solution:

```
 1.  Tlements in Z*_{30}(modulo of 30). ={1,2,3,.,n,n+1,......,29}
2. The function ~:Z*_{30}-->  Z*_{30}given for x is element of Z*_{30} by ~(x)=x^2 is a homomorphism for all x,y are elements of Z*_{30} holds that:
                  ~(x.y)= (x.y)^2= x^2.y^2=~(x).~(y).Thus ~ is a homomorphism.
3. the kernel, ker(~)={x element of Z*_{30}l~(x)= e}
                     = {x element of Z*_{30}lx^2= 1}
                      = {x element of Z*_{30}lx= sqrt1}
                       ={x element of Z*_{30}lx= 1}
therefore the ker(~) ={e}={1}
```

please check my solution

Comment: I've added a "preformatted code" block so your formatting sticks -- it's better to use markdown + latex if you get the chance to learn.

Comment: Look at the image of 29 under squaring homomorphism.

Comment: what is the preformatted code? but thanks anyway.

Comment: is the image of 29 =1?

Comment: I improved your question using Latex. Click on edit to see how I did it so you can learn for your next questions.

Comment: @PVanchinathan.ok. so that means that 29 is also one of the kernel.thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you need to be very precise when you list the elements in $\mathbb Z^*_{30}$. From the way you wrote it it is entirely unclear what the elements are. It's not even clear how many elements you claim there are in the group. You probably need to look again at the definition of this group and make sure you understand it properly. Once you'll find all the elements in the group you can compute $\varphi (x)$ for each and see when you get $e=1$. That will give you the kernel.

Comment: thank you sir.i have to check the the element again.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong,
 the elements for 〖Z^*〗_30:
[image]

Comment: In addition, the elements are those of integer modulo 30 but relatively prime to 30.